# Dismiss popover from other view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I have a `NavigationController` with 2  bar buttons say p1 ,p2 , each when pressed presents a presentation popover.

On pressing anywhere outside or close button in the popover, the popover closes successfully.

But, lets say if i press p2 -> p2 popover shows. After this if i press p1 then the p2 popover does not close and i have to press anywhere outside to close p1 first and then again press p2 to show p2.

How can I close p1 first and show p2 on mere pressing p2 in one go ?

Do I need to use `NSNotification` from p2 to p1 or can there be some other approach ?

I do not have IBaction routine for buttons and have directly used story board segues. i believe, I have to do the check if p1 is presented in p2 viewdidload and subsequently remove p1 and vice versa. This is what i am not getting. How to do this .

Comment: show your code !!

Comment: please share code and screenshot ..

Comment: You can use whole transparent view and use tap gesture to dismiss the shown pop up.

Comment: what code should i show ? i have a nav controller with 2 buttons and using storyboard segues its segued to 2 VCs as pop up. thats it .

Answer (score 0):

Please close first the popover programatically and then present second popover after delay(0.2 seconds)

Step1: Dismiss First Popover

```
self.popoverController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Step2: Present second popover after delay

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        <WRITE YOUR CODE HERE for present popover>
    });
```

Comment: how to do this from a different viewController's viewdidload method ?close first from second view controller's viewdidload.

Comment: There are two ways to do that. You can either use a delegate or NSNotificationCenter to call method from different viewController.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check on both buttons action method, that if the other popover is already visible then dissmiss that first then show another.

lets say if i press p2 -> p2 popover shows. After this if i press p1 then **first check if p2 is already presented or not, if it is already there then dismiss it and show p1** , apply same logic for p1.

something similar to this approach

```
- (void) p2 clicked {
   if([p1 alreadyPresented]){
       dismiss p1;
       present p2;
   }else{
       present p2;
   }
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

lets see an example to dissmiss other popovers,  I am a view controller A , and I have a @property(strong,nonatomic) of another view conroller B, I can dissmiss B using this code in any function defined inside me, say 
lets assume B is defined in A as

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) ViewControllerB *popoverB;
```

then do this inside A;

```
- (void) dismissB{ 
   if ([popoverB presentedViewController]) {
        [popoverB dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
         //Present here your Popover controller A here.
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the actuall question , how to check p1 already presented in p2 ? i do not have IBaction routine for buttons, i have directly used storyboard segues . i need to do the above check in both VC 's viewdidLoad.

Comment: see the update that I have added, from Nirav D's answer, this is how you dismiss other viewcontrollers from one controller.

Comment: i believe , its gonna be lil more. PopoverB is just another object of type ViewControllerB and not the actually one presented . May be i should  give my storyboard an id and then load it programatically , and then load the VC using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier and then do the above. But anyways , thanks for pointing out the "presentedViewController" method, dint know abt this.